# React Component not created until render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using Styled Components but getting a problem trying to style a component of my own creation.

It is exported in the normal way from a separate npm package.

Package

FormComponents.js

```
export SubmitButton from './_submit-button';
```

_submit-button.js

```
export styled.button`somestyles`;
```

components.js

```
import * as Form from './form-components';
export { Form }
```

index.js

```
import * as Components from './components'
export const FormComponents = Components.Form;
```

Then in my actual component I want to use it I have:

```
import { FormComponents as Form } from 'packagename';
const Button = styled(Form.SubmitButton)...
```

and I'm receiving the error cannot read SubmitButton of undefined.

If however I put the `const Button = ...` in the render method, it finds everything fine. So I assume that the component isn't being instantiated until React kicks in.

It's possible with other elements however, for example if I change it to use:

```
const Button = styled(Link)
```

(Link from react-router-dom)
it finds it fine.

Am I exporting wrong?